# CIGaussianBlur changes imageOrientation sometime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

In my iOS app I want to apply a filter CIGaussianBlur on UIImage, when it gets a image having big height it rotates the image

```
   CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:image];  //get image for blur

     CIFilter *blurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [blurFilter setDefaults];
    [blurFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    CGFloat blurLevel = 0.0f;          // Set blur level
    [blurFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:blurLevel] forKey:@"inputRadius"];

    // set value for blur level
    CIImage *outputImage = [blurFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    CGRect rect = inputImage.extent;    // Create Rect
    rect.origin.x += blurLevel;         // and set custom params
    rect.origin.y += blurLevel;         //
    rect.size.height -= blurLevel*2.0f; //
    rect.size.width -= blurLevel*2.0f;  //
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:rect];

    // Then apply new rect
    UIImageOrientation originalOrientation = _imageView.image.imageOrientation;
    CGFloat originalScale = _imageView.image.scale;

    UIImage *fixedImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:originalScale orientation:originalOrientation] ;  //output of CIGaussianBlur
```

Comment: it works for me 
  _imageView.image=image;
UIImageOrientation originalOrientation = _imageView.image.imageOrientation;
    CGFloat originalScale = _imageView.image.scale;
    
    UIImage *fixedImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:originalScale orientation:originalOrientation] ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me.

```
_imageView.image=image;

UIImageOrientation originalOrientation = _imageView.image.imageOrientation;

CGFloat originalScale = _imageView.image.scale;

UIImage *fixedImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:originalScale orientation:originalOrientation] ;
```