# UISlider which blurs image with CiGaussianBlur also rotates image

Tags: ios, uiimage, uislider, blur

I have a UISlider which has a range from 0 to 30.

Unfortunately, when I'm using the UISlider, the image starts to blur, BUT it also rotates.

Here's the code:

```
-(IBAction)slider:(UISlider *)sender
{
    float slideValue = [sender value];

    CIImage *beginImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:image];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputRadius", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:slideValue], nil];
    CIImage *outputImage = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[beginImage extent]];
    UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

    [imageView setImage:newImg];
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
}
```

Where is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the resulting image is rotated 90 degrees regardless of the slider position?

Comment: I recall recently seeing a question or two about such a problem. I think it is related to the conversion to or from UIImage and CIImage. Do some searching and you should find some relevant information.

Comment: Note, by the way, that should not be repeatedly calling `CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];` as it is very inefficient. Call it once and put the `context` in an instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
```

This is too simple-minded. Call `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg scale:originalScale orientation:originalOrientation];` (you will need to provide correct values for these).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185207/cigaussianblur-changes-imageorientation-sometime for example.

Comment: You're very welcome. Interesting problem; I edited the title to make it easier to find by searching.